# Convert string array into field names using javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Was wondering if there was a nice way in javascript, preferably es6, to convert a string array that was a result from a map function into field names in a dynamically created object.

For example, say I get the following result from my map function:

```
["checkbox1Value", "checkbox4Value"]
```

I would like to do this with those results:

```
const answer = {
     //some other fields dynamically created
     checkbox1Value: true,
     checkbox4Value: true 
}
```

Anyway of doing this via es6?

Answer (score 4):

You could use [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) and map the single objects and assign it to a single object.

```js
var array = ["checkbox1Value", "checkbox4Value"],
    object = Object.assign(...array.map(k => ({ [k]: true })));

console.log(object);
```

Comment: Great answer, but I have a feeling that this is inefficient for large arrays.

Comment: please define *large* arrays. i think the size is actually negligible.

Comment: What I meant was a sufficiently large array with thousands of elements. Since you are creating a new object for each for the elements, 1) it's unnecessary, 2) since they are dynamically passed to `Object.assign` as arguments, it would cause a StackOverflow for any sufficiently large arrays. (example: https://jsfiddle.net/3rs2jha1/) Using my solution for comparison purposes, `.reduce` only took 227ms while `Object.assign` took over 1000ms can caused a stack overflow.

Comment: the question was about a *nice*, *ES6* way to covert an array to an object with the values as keys. if the user would like to get a *fast* way for a huge array of keys, then in this case a simple `for` loop would be the best, which have a small footprint of moving an object around a reduce callback.

Comment: I would say that there exists a nice balance between convenient/readable ES6 code and efficiency. If efficiency is comprised, then it's not exactly a "nice ES6 way" of doing it. (Not that this is an invalid solution, I personally upvoted your answer.)

Comment: I like both Nina's and Derek's solutions!  This is what I was looking for!  I won't have more than 10 checkboxes so performance is not an issue, however it is nice to know if Derek is right about large arrays.  Too bad I can't give correct answers to both.  I upvoted both answers.

Answer (score 3):

```js
    let result = ["checkbox1Value", "checkbox4Value"];
    const answer = result.reduce((acc, cur) => {acc[cur] = true; return acc}, {});

    console.log(answer);
```

`.reduce` is really just a fancy `for` loop (an "ES6 way of doing it"). If you are shooting for maximum efficiency, use a regular `for` loop instead.

Comment: Never thought about using reduce (still relatively new to javascript).  Love this answer as well as Nina's!  Nice to know there are multiple "elegant" ways of doing this.  I upvoted your answer too.  Appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

```
const myArray = ["checkbox1Value", "checkbox4Value"];

let obj = {};

myArray.forEach(val => {
    obj[val] = true;
})

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Cleanest and easiest to read! Though maybe don't use `array` as a variable name :P

Comment: I agree, cleanest and easiest to read. I would personally use this in production as it means all members of all levels would understand it. Nina's and Dereks are cool but for inexperienced develops, they would struggle to work with that code base.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing extremely ES6-y about this:

```js
let keys = ["checkbox1Value", "checkbox4Value"];
let obj = {};
for (let key of keys) {
  obj[key] = true;
}
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Both map & reduce are ECMA5.  I think you're thinking of arrow functions.

Comment: @Archer See e.g. Nina's answer.

Comment: But yes. `map` and `reduce` are not ES6.

Comment: Besides, OP specifically asks for ES6 methods.  But meh - nice to have the option if they ever want to run it on IE :p

Comment: I feel like the appeal of ES6 usually leads to people asking for an ES6 solution when they actually mean a functionally programmed solution

Comment: @ZekeDroid Actually both.  I actually had Aurel's code before but wanted to see a more "elegant" solution, thinking could be done functionally using ES6 notation.  All these answers are good though!

Comment: Absolutely, both very valuable thoughts

Answer (score 1):

You could map it to an object like so

```
const obj = {}
["checkbox1Value", "checkbox4Value"].forEach(val => {
    obj[val] = true
}
```

Comment: Probably wanna use `forEach` instead of `map`

Comment: yeah realised that as soon as I posted. Updated now